# How do I have an array that has a set of coordinates in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to record the coordinates in an array.  So I want to record something like {{0,0},{0,1},{1,1}}.  I thought about separating both integers by a space, and have the entire thing as a string, so (15 5) would be different than (1 55).  I assume it's not very efficient, and using string arrays are very difficult.

Here's the (bad) code I have so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    bool going=true;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    string coordinates[] = {};
    while (going==true){
        to_string(y)+","+to_string(x) >> coordinates;
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What do I use?

Comment: `operator>>` (in that direction) to a c-style array? Wake up!

Comment: Sorry.  I don't have any books on c++.

Comment: @chamington That's why I proposed you to follow that link.

Comment: May want to extend that link to encompass more text in the future. Can't speak for others, but my crap colour vision has a really hard time picking out links. I had to go back and scan the text with the mouse to see that a link was there. One or two words may not cut it.

Answer (score 6):

Make a `struct`!

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Then you can make an array of `Point`s:

```
std::array<Point, 3> array = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 } };
```

You could even overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` for easy input/output:

```
//For output
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    os << p.x << ", " << p.y << '\n';
    return os;
}

//For input
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Point& p)
{
    is >> p.x >> p.y;
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the (many, many) cases where you'll want to use the type system to help you. A coordinate is a type of object in your domain, so you can create a `Coordinate` class:

```
class Coordinate {
public:
  int x, y;
};
```

The Coordinate class is a blueprint for Coordinate objects. You can create instances of that class for every coordinate pair you have and insert it in your array.

Depending on whether you know the amount of coordinate pairs in advance or not, you might also want to use the `std::vector` class, which is like a dynamically resizeable array. Your code then becomes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Coordinate {
public:
  int x, y;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    bool going=true;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    vector<Coordinate> coordinates;
    while (going==true){
        Coordinate c { x, y };
        coordinates.push_back(c);
        x++;
        // Somehow break out of this loop
    }
    // coordinates contains all your { x, y } pairs
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Vector of struct

```
struct TwoDPoint
{
    int x, y;
};

std::vector< TwoDPoint > coordinates;
```

**2.** struct/class of vectors

```
class Coordinates
{
     std::vector < int > x;
     std::vector < int > y;
public:
    ...
    insert( int x, int y ){}
};
```

**3.**

```
std::pair< int, int > coordinate;
std::vector< std::pair< int, int > > coordinates;
```

**4.**

```
std::unordered_map< int, std::unordered_set< int > > coordinates;

It looks weird but could be useful if you have a lot of same x/y values (i.e. {1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,4})
```

5-6. Substitute `std::vector` with `std::unordered_set` in 1,3, respectively.

7+. If you really need array, then use some of the above but change `std::vector` with `std::array`. Also, you may use C arrays but you probably should not.